# C - error confliciting types. Function prototypes are defined

Tags: c, function

I'm in the beginning stages of creating a C compiler. I just want to do some simple error handling.

Can someone please explain why I'm still getting:

"conflicting type for 'abort' "

even though I've defined the function prototype for abort() and the signatures match?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "Concat.c"

/* Constant declarations */
const char TAB = '\t';

/* Variable Declarations */
char look;  /* Lookahead character */


/* Declaring function prototypes */
void getChar();
void error(char*);
void abort(char*);



/* Read new character fron input stream */
void getChar(){
    read(look);
}

/* Report an error */
void error(char* s) {
    // printf("%s\n", s);
    perror(s); 
}


/* Report an error and halt (return in C)  */
void abort(char *s) {
    perror(s);
    return;
}



/* Main Program */ 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /* tab test */
    printf("%c\n", TAB);

    /* error test */
    char *p;
    p = "Error Test";
    error(p);

    /* abort test */
    p = "Abort Test";
    abort(p);
}
```

Comment: Existing library function: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/abort

Comment: thank you so much! I'm still a beginner in C.

Comment: Never declare functions of the standard library yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> ## 7.22.4.1  The `abort` function
>
> ### Synopsis
>
> ```
>     #include <stdlib.h>
>     _Noreturn void abort(void);
> ```
>
> . . .